# DES Encryption from Angular to Spring boot and vice versa not working

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, encryption

I have implemented Encryption on both angular and spring boot sides, on either side I have used DES cryptography algorithm, the problem is `ciphertext` generated by Angular is not decoded on Spring Boot side and vice versa.

**Angular:**

```
convertText() {
    if (this.textToConvert.trim() === '' || this.password.trim() === '') {
      this.conversionOutput = 'Please fill the textboxes.';
      return;
    } else {
      if (this.encryptMode) {
        this.conversionOutput = CryptoJS.DES.encrypt(
          this.textToConvert.trim(),
          this.password.trim()
        ).toString();
      } else {
        this.conversionOutput = CryptoJS.DES.decrypt(
          this.textToConvert.trim(),
          this.password.trim()
        ).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
      }
    }
  }
```

**Java:**

**ENCRYPTION**:

```
public static String encryptWithKey(String str, String keyText) {
        if (str == null) {
            return null;
        }
        Cipher ecipher = null;
        Cipher dcipher = null;
        byte[] salt = {
                (byte) 0xA9, (byte) 0x9B, (byte) 0xC8, (byte) 0x32,
                (byte) 0x56, (byte) 0x35, (byte) 0xE3, (byte) 0x03
        };
        int iterationCount = 3;

        try {
            KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(keyText.toCharArray(), salt, iterationCount);
            SecretKey key = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(ALGO_NAME).generateSecret(keySpec);

            ecipher = Cipher.getInstance(key.getAlgorithm());
            dcipher = Cipher.getInstance(key.getAlgorithm());

            AlgorithmParameterSpec paramSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(salt, iterationCount);

            ecipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, paramSpec);
            dcipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, paramSpec);
        } catch (java.security.InvalidKeyException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            log.error("error in InvalidKeyException in encryptWithKey method for string : " + str + ",key : " + keyText + " : " + " : " + e.getMessage());
        }
        try {
            byte[] utf8 = str.getBytes("UTF8");
//            utf8 = fromHexString(str);
            byte[] enc = ecipher.doFinal(utf8);
//            return new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode(enc);
            return org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(enc);
//            return asHex(enc);

        } catch (javax.crypto.BadPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            log.error("error in BadPaddingException in encryptWithKey method for string : " + str + ",key : " + keyText + " : " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            log.error("error in IllegalBlockSizeException in encryptWithKey method for string : " + str + ",key : " + keyText + " : " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            log.error("error in UnsupportedEncodingException in encryptWithKey method for string : " + str + ",key : " + keyText + " : " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            log.error("error in NullPointerException in encryptWithKey method for string : " + str + ",key : " + keyText + " : " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }
```

**DECRYPTION:**

```
public static String decryptWithKey(String str, String keyText) {
        if (str == null || str.trim().equals("")) {
            return null;
        }
//        Cipher ecipher = null;
        Cipher dcipherLoc = null;
        byte[] salt = {
                (byte) 0xA9, (byte) 0x9B, (byte) 0xC8, (byte) 0x32,
                (byte) 0x56, (byte) 0x35, (byte) 0xE3, (byte) 0x03
        };
        int iterationCountLoc = 3;
        try {
            KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(keyText.toCharArray(), salt, iterationCountLoc);
            SecretKey key = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(ALGO_NAME).generateSecret(keySpec);

//            ecipher = Cipher.getInstance(key.getAlgorithm());
            dcipherLoc = Cipher.getInstance(key.getAlgorithm());

            AlgorithmParameterSpec paramSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(salt, iterationCountLoc);

//            ecipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, paramSpec);
            dcipherLoc.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, paramSpec);
        } catch (java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            log.error("error in InvalidAlgorithmParameterException in decryptWithKey method for string : " + str + ",key : " + keyText + " : " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            log.error("error in InvalidKeySpecException in decryptWithKey method for string : " + str + ",key : " + keyText + " : " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            log.error("error in NoSuchPaddingException in decryptWithKey method for string : " + str + ",key : " + keyText + " : " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            log.error("error in NoSuchAlgorithmException in decryptWithKey method for string : " + str + ",key : " + keyText + " : " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (java.security.InvalidKeyException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            log.error("error in InvalidKeyException in decryptWithKey method for string : " + str + ",key : " + keyText + " : " + e.getMessage());
        }
        try {
//            byte[] dec = new sun.misc.BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(str);
            byte[] dec = org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64(str);
//            byte[] dec = fromHexString(str);
            byte[] utf8 = dcipherLoc.doFinal(dec);
            return new String(utf8, "UTF8");

        } catch (javax.crypto.BadPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            log.error("error in BadPaddingException in decryptWithKey method for string : " + str + ",key : " + keyText + " : " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            log.error("error in IllegalBlockSizeException in decryptWithKey method for string : " + str + ",key : " + keyText + " : " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            log.error("error in UnsupportedEncodingException in decryptWithKey method for string : " + str + ",key : " + keyText + " : " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            log.error("error in NullPointerException in decryptWithKey method for string : " + str + ",key : " + keyText + " : " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return "Invalid String";
    }
```

**PROBLEM:**

lets try to encode the string at angular end and try to decrypt the same in Spring boot

**plain text:** admin123

**key:** secretkey (common in both the end)

**cipher text:** U2FsdGVkX1/FV1+LoXaVyi7Aco0JOgl5BDXwL18Zqoc=

When I tried to decrypt the abve cipher text at spring boot end

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Decrypt With Key=" + decryptWithKey("U2FsdGVkX1/FV1+LoXaVyi7Aco0JOgl5BDXwL18Zqoc=","secretkey"));
    }
```

**TRACE:**

```
javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used during decryption.
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.unpad(CipherCore.java:975)
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.fillOutputBuffer(CipherCore.java:1056)
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:853)
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.PBES1Core.doFinal(PBES1Core.java:432)
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.PBEWithMD5AndDESCipher.engineDoFinal(PBEWithMD5AndDESCipher.java:316)
    at java.base/javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2202)
    at com.nl.core.crypto.util.DesEncrypter.decryptWithKey(DesEncrypter.java:230)
    at com.nl.core.crypto.util.DesEncrypter.main(DesEncrypter.java:290)
18:59:00.920 [main] ERROR com.netlink.core.crypto.util.DesEncrypter - error in BadPaddingException in decryptWithKey method for string : U2FsdGVkX1/FV1+LoXaVyi7Aco0JOgl5BDXwL18Zqoc=,key : secetkey : Given final block not properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used during decryption.
Decrypt With Key=Invalid String
```

It seems the `secretkey` is not working for decode mechanism, I am not able to figured it out what went wrong, as I am using DES at both the sides.

Comment: The key used for en_/decryption (I do **not mean** the "String keyText") differ from Angular to Java - on later you derive the key using **PBKDF2** from the key string so decryption has to fail because the "real" keys differ. Btw: the DES algorithm is **outdated** and **insecure** and you should not longer this algorithm.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion could you please demonstrate the same by posting some releavnt code snippets

Comment: and thank you for he suggestion, the project itself outdated the angular integration is the new thing, btw which algorithm would you like to recommend?

Comment: Before posting any code samples you should be clear what encryption algorithm you like to use and thinking about the encryption key (or the key derivation). As said, DES is outdated since a long time and I'm not using it anymore...

Comment: I do aware, the problem is this project is legacy, we are somehow trying to convince the client to leverage the advantages and power of TripleDES , AES or IDEA, as of now we need to give the solution on the same implementation, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you say "this project is legacy" - which part (SpringBoot/Java or Angular)? Just for anyone else who tries to find a solution for the "other" framework.

Comment: Majority of the codebase has been developed using strust2.x, for sake of exposing the rest api, we've integrate the Spring boot part, which will be the centralized wrapper, we are on POC phase where we need to authenticate the user using the JWT token, but for the sake of securing the communication channel between frontend and backend we need to implement the encryption mechanism.